# Variable with counter that increases automatically

Tags: counters

I want to define a variable that does the following

```
\newcounter{ver}
\newcommand{\version}[1][]{Version ~\thever ##1 \addtocounter{ver}{1}}
```

The idea is that whenever you write the command `\version` it will display the version number and add a 1 as well to the number. But I got an error when I wrote the above command "You can't use macro parameter..."

Any idea how to define such a variable

Comment: The `##1` in the definition causes the error. Do you want `\##1` or `#1`? Or maybe just `\newcommand{\version}{Version~\thever\addtocounter{ver}{1}}`?

Comment: Thank you removing # solves the problem.. but can you please explain to me what’s the different between ##1 and #1

Comment: It is basically down to nesting definitions. If they both use arguments then we need to be able to refer to which macro a argument placeholder is referring to. So at each nesting leven the number of `#` doubles. Thus `##1` is referring to an argument on nesting level 2`

Answer (score 2):

`##` in a definition is `#` and `#1` in a definition means the first argument, so `##1` produces  `#1`  in the replacement text, so giving an error that you can not have `#` at that point.

Also you could replace

```
 \addtocounter{ver}{1}
```

by

```
\stepcounter{ver}
```

(note no space before the command)

or better

```
\refstepcounter{ver}
```

If you use `\refstepcounter` you will be able to use `\version{zzz}\label{myver}....  see \ref{myver}`